# Find command not working as expected in centOS

Tags: linux, unix, centos, find, redhat

I am using CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 on virtual box. I am trying to find the files using find command.

this find command is not giving any response:

```
find . -name "orm.properties"
```

My current working directory is `/eserver6`. File `orm.properties` is present in `/eserver6/share/system/config/cluster`, but `find` command is not able to find the file.

I have tried other combinations like

```
find . -name "orm.*"
find . -name 'orm*'
```

this is finding few files staring with orm but not all the files present inside the current working directory.

Comment: note `find .` will start from your current directory. Where are you? `pwd` can tell. You can also try `find /eserver6/share/system/config/cluster -name "orm.properties"`. Make sure also that you don't have any alias indicating `min/maxdepth`.

Comment: I am in correct working directory. I am in eserver6 directory which has soft link share -> /var/opt/eserver6/share this soft link location contains orm.properties. Is it because of softlink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line looks correct and it should find the file. Some reasons why it might fail:

1. You don't have permission to enter one of the folders in the path to `/eserver6/share/system/config/cluster`.
2. You made a typo
3. The file system is remote and the remote file system behaves oddly
4. There is a simlink somewhere in the path. By default, `find` doesn't follow symlinks to avoid recursive loops. Use `find /eserver6 -L ...` to tell `find` to look at the target of the link and follow it if it's a folder.

The command

```
find /eserver6 -name "orm.properties"
```

should definitely find the file, no matter where you are. If it doesn't, look at `-D debugoptions` in the manpage. You probably want `-D stat` to see at which files `find` looks and what it sees.

Comment: Another possibility: one of the directories in that path is a symbolic link, in which case "find" will need the -L option.

Comment: I am in correct working directory. I am in eserver6 directory which has soft link share -> /var/opt/eserver6/share this soft link location contains orm.properties. Is it because of softlink?

Comment: @Vivek: Yes. By default, `find` doesn't follow symlinks to avoid recursive loops. Use `find /eserver6 -L ...`

Answer (score 0):

If your user have entry into `sudoers` file then its ok and you can run

```
sudo find / -name "orm.properties"
```

or else ask your admin to give an entry in `sudoer`s file of your user and run the same command then it will work.

Comment: this can take forever to run

Comment: @fedorqui no sir if he don't know the exact location of that file then he must go through this, if he knows the exact location of the file then there is no scene of finding an known file location by `find` command